# Dynamically Built DOM via jQuery For Loop Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Apologies in advance... this seems so straightforward but it's as iff my append in the for loop acts as an html method and overwrites the inner html.

```
$(function () {
    var wrapper = $('<div />', {
        class: 'row'
    }),
    button = $('<div />', {
        class: 'column'
    }),
    buttons = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        var btn = (i % 2)? button.html(i + 1) : button.addClass('last').html(i + 1);
        buttons.push(btn);
        if (i % 2) {
            console.log('buttons', buttons);
            $('.container').append(wrapper.append(buttons));
            console.log('wrapper', wrapper);
            console.log('container', $('.container'));
            buttons = [];
        }
    }
});
```

[Fiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/anthonygreco/yd0kz8wj/)

Comment: What is your issue? Question's title and text look unclear for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

when you a object created outside in a loop to add to multiple elements, you need to clone them else you will be just replacing the element from one location to another

```
$(function () {
    var wrapper = $('<div />', {
        class: 'row'
    }),
        button = $('<div />', {
            class: 'column'
        }),
        btn, wr;
    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        btn = button.clone().html(i + 1);
        if (i % 2 == 0) {
            wr = wrapper.clone().appendTo('.container');
            btn.addClass('last')
        }
        wr.append(btn)
    }
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/ede0mxvy/)